# Application Server info into resource adapter

Tags: java, websphere

I have a resource adapter which would be deployed in different application servers.  But i need to write some code specific to WebSphere.  How do i get the application server info into my resource adapter code?  Or more specifically how do i know in which application server it is deployed at runtime?

Comment: What are you trying to do that's WebSphere-specific?  Typically, you would use something like `try { Class.forName("<something websphere specific>") } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}`.

Comment: Similar to that, like,   
if <websphere> then
        <websphere specific API> 
else  if <weblogic> then 
   <weblogic specific API>
else
    <default>

Comment: Then I would use `Class.forName("<websphere specific API>")` to detect if you're running on WebSphere.